# Why is my Google Analytics callto event tracking code not tracking?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to track a call tel event when a button is clicked. My GA code was provided from the setup wizard.

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={{site.google_analytics_tracking_id}}"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', '{{site.google_analytics_tracking_id}}');
    </script>
```

And my button code is:

```html
<!-- Banner -->
<section id="banner">
    <div class="inner">
        <header>
            <h2>{{ site.title }}</h2>
            <figure>
                <picture class="image logo">
                    <span class="icon logo fa-balance-scale"></span>
                </picture>
                <figcaption><small>Serving: {{ site.location }}</small></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </header>
        <p><strong>We Work Hard To Protect Your Rights!</strong></p>
        <footer>
            <ul class="buttons stacked">
                <button class="button fit">Call: <a href="tel:{{site.tel}}" onClick=”ga('send', 'event', 'Calls', 'clicked', 'Contact Office', 1);”>{{site.tel}}</a></button>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
```

## Vote

Please up or down vote the question. Before down voting, suggest edits or leave comments?

Comment: do this kind of double quote work? `”`

Comment: @GrafiCode what do you mean?

Comment: Double quotes should be standard

Comment: Vote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have GA implemented via gtag.js, the function you used for onClick is for analytics.js, so you need to use [the right functions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events).
You need to do it in this format:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

so for your example:

```
gtag('event', 'clicked', {
  'event_category': 'Calls',
  'event_label': 'Contact Office',
  'value': 1
});
```

Comment: I had an invalid character in the onclick parameter! Works now with your code.

Comment: Vote my question?